# batch file to check vpn connection when is online/up

Tags: batch-file, connection, vpn, errorlevel

I need to check the vpn connection when is online/up with a batch file.

**Actually i use this code:**

```
PING -n 5 www.google.com|FIND /I "TTL">NUL

IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
Echo "Vpn Connection Is Up"
)
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
Echo "Vpn Connection Is Down"
)
```

Sometimes the ping give a non response or give a general failure response.

I would like to know that there is a better batch code alternative than the ping command.

I tried this alternative codes but do not recognize vpn when is online/up because the adapter is always in my pc installed.

**First Alternative Code:**

```
ipconfig|find /i "VPN" && GOTO startAPP || GOTO connectVPN
```

**Second Alternative Code:**

```
ipconfig|find /i "VPN"

if %errorlevle%==1 goto:connectVPN

echo Starting APP !
exit/b

:connectVPN
echo connecting to VPN
```

**Third Alternative Code:**

```
:start
cls
rasdial | find /I "%vpnname%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto vpndown
if errorlevel 0 goto vpnup
```

Can You recommend an alternative command to ping to be integrated into my batch code please ?

The alternatives code do not recognize when vpn connection is online, it's recognize if exist the adampter installed in my pc but i need to know when vpn is online/up (ready to go on internet).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that, is to use `rasdial` command, which is used for VPN connections. Especially, use:

```bat
@echo off

rasdial | findstr /ic:"No" >nul
if not %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo Found a VPN connection!
    goto :found
) else (
    echo We didn't find any VPN connections!
    goto :notfound
)

:found
rem Do something if a VPN connection is found/online:

:notfound
rem Do something if a VPN connection isn't found/online:
```

Comment: This code do not recognize the vpn online, have not any command to detect the vpn name

Comment: After i connect the vpn via openvpn, I go on internet, if i open cmd.exe and type rasdial show "no connection" but vpn is connect and i'm online on internet. rasdial can detect when openvpn is connected ?

Comment: I use openvpn and i search a solution to check connection of openvpn client please

Comment: For me the code works if you replace the 2nd line by this: `ping <ENTER_HOST_BEHIND_VPN> | find /I /C "could not find host" > NUL` where <ENTER_HOST_BEHIND_VPN> is a host only available when VPN is active.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you incorporate powershell into your batch (or powershell on its own) you can see if connection is up.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('powershell "Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status" ^| findstr /i "Wifi"') do (
   if /i "%%i"=="up" echo VPN %%i
   if /i "%%i"=="down" echo VPN %%i
)
```

You could also make it ping google, first, then if an issue is found, ping the gateway, if there's an issue, check the connection, something almost like this:

```
@echo off
:start
ping -n 2 www.google.com | findstr /i "ttl">nul
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
    echo "Oops something is wrong, let's test gateway"
    goto testgate
) else (
    echo "Internet Still reachable"
    timeout 5 /nobreak>nul
    goto start
)

:testgate
ping -n 2 10.3.1.1 | findstr /i "ttl">nul
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
    echo "Hmm, gateway also not reachable, will test VPN"
        for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('powershell "Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status" ^| findstr /i "VPN"') do (
           if /i "%%i"=="up" (
               echo "Adapter connection %%i, will retry internet ping now"
               goto start
     ) else  (
               echo Adapter connection Down or Disconnected
               echo let's start something up
               pause
               goto start
               goto :eof
           )
        )
      ) else (
          echo "Gateway Connection Is Up"
          goto start
 )
```

Comment: My code works like a charms but i need a solution without ping because sometimes ping give a non response or a general failure response

Comment: @camomillo ok, then why not incorporate powershell? will ammend my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is using `netsh wlan show networks`. This command will show you your current connected network adapter. We can use `find /I "VPN"` to look is your *VPN* is currently connected. The `%ERRORLEVEL%` will allow you to extract a yes/no.

**Is-VPN-Up.Bat:**

```
netsh wlan show networks | FIND "VPN" /I /C >NUL
IF Not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
    Echo "Vpn Connection Is Up"
) ELSE (
    Echo "Vpn Connection Is Down"
)
```

Comment: This code do not work, i connected the vpn and your code always show "Vpn Connection Is Down". I use openvpn to connect vpn.

Comment: @camomillo Another option is to compare your current IP and check if your global IP has changed.

Comment: I use openvpn to connect to a vpn, I need a solution diffferent ping to know when openvpn is connected and from now i can open the browser to go on internet, thanks